# Appending values of two lists in python in a specific way

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [[],[],[]]
```

and i want to obtain this output:

```
[['a'], [], []]
[['a'], ['b'], []]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a']]     
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

I have tried doing this but it does not work:

```
def func():
    list1 = ['a','b','c']
    list2 = [[],[],[]]
    print(list1)
    for i in list1:
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            list2[j].append(i)
            print(list2)
        
func()
```

how can i receive my desired output?

Comment: here are the answers, please create a new question if you have new requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working code, which gives the desired output:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [[],[],[]]
size = len(list1)

for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        list2[i].append(list1[(i+j)%size])
        print(list2)
```

Outputs:

```
[['a'], [], []]
[['a'], ['b'], []]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

For second part of the question, you just place the print statement where you need it:

```
for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        list2[i].append(list1[(i+j)%size])
    print(list2)
```

Output is:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [[],[],[]]
for _ in list1:
    for j, val2 in enumerate(list2):
        val2.append(list1[j])
        print(list2)
    list1 = list1[1:] + [list1[0]]
```

gives the following output :

```
['a'], [], []]
[['a'], ['b'], []]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

You could then do a :

```
list2 = [sorted(i) for i in list2]
```

to get the final line with the letters in alphabetical order. This works for any two lists where len(list1) == len(list2).

Comment: @malo 's response is better than mine (y)